# Textbox start typing backwards when you move curser out of Microsoft Teams Tab

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-teams

We have SharePoint framework app embedded into a SharePoint page and added to Teams as a tab. textbox (basic HTML) start typing backwards when you move your curser outside the tab area (either to Teams chat area or side navigation).

Steps to reproduce

1. Type something in the textbox (I have textbox in my SPFX webpart)
2. Highlight the text with the curser and hold selection (hold left button)
3. Move the mouse pointer to Teams chat area or navigation are but don't click anything
4. Start typing. Whatever you type will be backwards